# create xml with self closing tag in vba

Tags: xml, vba

I am building an xml file for my office work.
I require the Structure of xml to be as follows

```
<MultiBlock xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="x-
schema:ConfigFileSchema.xml">
<Model>
<ModelName type="AlarmGroup">Alarm Groups</ModelName>
</Model>
<ErdbVersion>
<DbVersion>12.0</DbVersion>
</ErdbVersion>
</MultiBlock>
```

and My code is :

```
Sub create_alarmgroup()
Dim objDom As DOMDocument
Dim objRootElem As IXMLDOMElement       
Dim objMemberElem As IXMLDOMElement     
Dim objmembervar As IXMLDOMElement      
Dim objmemberatt As IXMLDOMAttribute    
Const QUOTE_MARK As Integer = 34
Dim xmlVersion As MSXML2.IXMLDOMProcessingInstruction   
Set objDom = New DOMDocument

Set xmlVersion = objDom.createProcessingInstruction("xml", "version=" & 
Chr(QUOTE_MARK) & "1.0" & Chr(QUOTE_MARK))
objDom.appendChild xmlVersion

'Creates root element
Set objRootElem = objDom.createElement("MultiBlock")
objRootElem.setAttribute "xmlns", "x-schema:ConfigFileSchema.xml"

objRootElem.setAttribute "xmlns:xsd", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"

objRootElem.setAttribute "xmlns:xsi", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-
instance"
objDom.appendChild objRootElem

'==========ROOT ELEMENT END================

'Create Member element - MODEL
Set objMemberElem = objDom.createElement("Model")
objMemberElem.Text = " "

objRootElem.appendChild objMemberElem

Set objmembervar = objDom.createElement("ModelName")
Set objmemberatt = objDom.createAttribute("type")
objmemberatt.NodeValue = "AlarmGroup"
objmembervar.setAttributeNode objmemberatt
objmembervar.Text = "Alarm Groups"

objMemberElem.appendChild objmembervar

Set objMemberElem = objDom.createElement("ErdbVersion")
objMemberElem.Text = " "
objRootElem.appendChild objMemberElem
Set objmembervar = objDom.createElement("DbVersion")
objmembervar.Text = "12.0"
objRootElem.appendChild objmembervar


'Save to disk
Cells(5, 1).Select
objDom.Save (ThisWorkbook.Path & "\srcvariables.cnf.xml")

End Sub
```

But i am not able to create a closing tag at "Model", "ErdbVersion" Nodes. I dont want to use the self closing tags for my xml and require traditional xml.

Please guide.

Comment: the meaning of your last sentence is not clear. the _and require traditional xml_ part.

Comment: Your question is not clear. Please show the ACTUAL output.

Comment: Apart from attaching `DbVersion` as a child of the root element rather than a child of `ErdbVersion`, your code seems to be producing what you want to produce.  (Change `objRootElem.appendChild objmembervar` to `objMemberElem.appendChild objmembervar` to fix that.)  What do you mean by `i am not able to create a closing tag at "Model"`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the way to add closing Tag.
I had set the xml element's text property as " "

```
xmlelement.text= " "
```